# Laravel 8: Get server IP address when using an HTTP Client

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm utilizing the new `HTTP Client` within the Laravel 8 framework, which I use to call my APIs for certain micro-services.

How can I attain the Server IP of each sender when I receive a response? All of my clients are specifically client websites hosted on various servers online.

Here's a sample function:

```php
$response = Http::post('https://example.com', [
    'id' => $id
]);
```

EDIT: `https://example.com` is my server. I need the Server IP of the Clients sending the requests.

Comment: Are you asking how to find the IP address of the server you're sending _to_, in this example  `example.com`?

Comment: No, the IP address sending to ` example.com` @IMSoP

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#request-ip-address

Comment: If `example.com` is your server, it doesn't matter (and you can't know) how someone sent the HTTP request _to_ you, so you've shown us the wrong code. The code you need to be looking at is where you _receive_ the request.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I guess I misunderstood it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel has a function in its api :

```
Request::ip();
```

from which you can get the client ip from his request on your application or
you can use php methods to access client ip in array of `$_SERVER[]` as :

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']` will give you the contents of the (non-standard, I think?) `Client-IP` HTTP header, which could be set to anything the client wanted. To get the _actual_ IP address that connected, you need `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` - but that might just be a load balancer or proxy, in which case you need to know what headers _that particular setup_ will add that you can trust to give you the external IP address that connected to it. (It may be that in your setup, that happens to be `Client-IP`, which is why this is the code you've remembered.)

Comment: @IMSoP yes all true , $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] is just a a header value and can be changed by client so in this case $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is more reliable because is transmitted to you by webserver handling the request but agian as you said also this can be a proxy and only the person behind the proxy can suggest you for which header to request and rely on . So at least $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is most reliable IP address always  if the setup is normal.